# Corrupt image when extract from zip

Tags: php, nginx

I trying download a zip file using curl from one virtual host to another, in a same server. Zip file contains *.php and *.jpg files.

The problem is: **sometimes JPG files get corrupt**, like this:

[image: jpg file]

Here is my code :

```
$out = fopen(ABSPATH.'/templates/default.zip','w+'); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://share.example.com/templates/default.zip'); 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 


$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open(ABSPATH.'/templates/default.zip') === TRUE) 
{
    if($zip->extractTo(ABSPATH.'/templates'))
    {
        echo 'OK';
    }

    $zip->close();
} 

//$zip->close();
```

I don't understand what happen to my jpg. I also tried using pclzip.lib.php, but no luck. How to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Trying to rule out the obvious - if you download and unzip the file normally (i.e. manually, without PHP) does it work?

Comment: Yes its work. File Uploaded to server using FTP binary mode (i have tried ascii mode too), Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I know that zip files can have different algorithms. Maybe there is a compatibility issue?

Comment: Please compare CRC checksums. What do they say? (The CRC checksums are stored inside the ZIP file).

Comment: Judging from your code, it doesn't seem like you're doing anything wrong; have you looked around at http://bugs.php.net/ ?

Comment: well not sure about bug-reports, but I'd say there is not much of the code shared to say it's okay. You should offer the whole example and a link to the zip file as well so it's possible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You say that sometimes. Can you figure out when this "sometimes" happens?

Comment: @hakre: i dont understand about crc checksums, but i'll check, thanks.

Comment: @PLB: yes, sometimes. can another server process (ie: antivirus or anything) make an image become corrupt ?

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul: My fault, the ZIP file does not contain it, but you can create it your own and output. Numbers / strings are more save than binary data, so you have some checksum to validate the zips content as well as PHP's ability to extract it. If it's the same with the standard download, it shows that you made the error and this is not a PHP bug.

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul Yes, I think that some server process corrupts image. otherwise decompressing algorithm is not working well (if so it's bug and I have no idea, how to fix it).

Comment: Do you have control over the other server? Maybe you could use gz instead of zip, and see if the same issue happens. That would at least rule out the decompression bug.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but have you tried opening the zip file for writing like `'wb+'`? Normally adding `b` doesn't make a difference, but maybe here it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found what is the problem.

I'm using Nginx web server, when i change nginx config files:

```
sendfile on;
```

became

```
sendfile off;
```

My image not corrupt anymore. So its not php or curl problem. Interesting article: http://technosophos.com/node/172

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading the file via curl and unzipping it normally (i.e. without php)? To figure out whether the download causes the problem or the unzip.

You might also try to replace one of both parts using shell_exec (wget instead of curl, unzip instead of ZipArchive). I mean just for debugging, not for production maybe.